# Retrieve Product Attribute Label in event catalog_entity_attribute_save_before

Tags: attributes

How can I change the label associated with an attribute in the catalog_entity_attribute_save_before event?

When I say label, I mean the value set here:

Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Click on an attribute -> Manage Labels / Options -> Manage Titles -> Admin

I have tried this in my observer, but `$attribute->getLabel()` returns NULL.

```
class NS1_ProductAttributeSpacesAndProperty_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalog_entity_attribute_save_before($observer)
    {
        $attribute = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute();

        $entityTypeId = $attribute->getEntityTypeId();
        if($entityTypeId == 4)
        {
            // the attribute is a product attribute
            $label = $attribute->getLabel();
            echo gettype($label);exit; // prints NULL
            //$attribute->setLabel("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

I have managed to retrieve the label with `$attribute->getFrontendLabel()`, but I am still unable to update the attribute label before it saves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this now by using:

```
$labels = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();

$labels[0] = 'blah';

$attribute->setFrontendLabel($labels);
```

Comment: Just for future reference, `frontend_label` should be an array. The key will be the store ID, and the value the label for that store ID. In your case, "0" is the Admin Store.

Comment: Fantastic thanks, I see that it's 1 array element per column in the GUI.