# How to check uniquenes of color options when adding a color magento 2?

Tags: magento2, color-swatches, unique-constraint

I want that when i add an  existing color an exception will be raised so how to proceed and which file do i have to override and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function to check color value already exists or not as follows:

```
protected $_resource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
) {
    $this->_resource = $resource;
}

public function checkColorExists($color) {
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);

    $result = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT DISTINCT value FROM `eav_attribute_option_value` WHERE option_id IN (SELECT option_id FROM `eav_attribute_option` WHERE `attribute_id` = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'color'))");

    foreach ($result as &$value) {
        $value = $value['value'];
    }

    if (in_array($color, $result)) {
        // Throw exception
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this may helpful!

Comment: do i have to put this code in observer event  catalog_entity_attribute_save_before to check or in other place and thanks for your replay

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I have not tried yet catalog_entity_attribute_save_before event, but yes ofcourse try once. And if works fine, then please accept this answer.

Comment: ok i will check this immediatly

Comment: i can't understand this part of your code foreach ($result as &$value) {
        $value = $value['value'];
    } what that mean

Comment: Please do echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); before and after foreach. You will get idea.

Comment: ok and how to call this function in my observer please

Comment: Put this function in any Helper and call that helper in your observer.

Comment: perfect ok i will do that

Comment: and when calling the function from helper in observer what is the color as argument that i should put ???

Comment: You will get saved color value in observer as described in this link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56380/retrieve-product-attribute-label-in-event-catalog-entity-attribute-save-before. You need to pass $attribute->getFrontendLabel();

Comment: so i should make a foreach  as below $this->_productAttributeRepository->get('color')->getOptions(); and then call my function to test if $option['label'] exists or not

Comment: or  like this         $attribute = $observer->getEvent()->getAttribute('color');
 and then $labels = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
 and then a foreach and calling the function colorexists ???

Comment: @DevelopperMagento Simply you have to create observer, call helper, pass $attribute->getFrontendLabel(); in the function which I written. Then go to admin products attribute, select color attribute and try to save duplicate option label. At that point you should get exception. This is your requirement. Am I right or not?

Comment: i want to test if the label of the new added color does not exist in the collections of color already created and not the label of the attribute

Comment: For "how to get new color label in observer", you need to create new question. Other than that I advice you to test my function, you can create controller, call helper  and simply pass any duplicate color label.

Comment: yes brother it works for label of attribute but i need to know  How to check uniquenes of color options when adding a color magento 2? and the idea is similar but just i am stuck in   saving the color if it's ok now i get the  exception if i add an existig label but i can't delete this color added and put a new one

Comment: Can you please try this event "catalog_product_attribute_update_before"?

Comment: ok i will check it